# Font not initializing but only on three pages

Tags: wordpress, css, google-chrome, firefox

I posted about this issue with a client's site previously but I was unable to explain it thoroughly or properly. I'm going to re-iterate my issue in hopes that somebody can assist me with a solution.

I have a WordPress site using the Jupiter theme and Masterkey framework and through that, I am loading Google Fonts. My navigation is set to use the font Cinzel and it loads perfectly fine on every page except for a few.

Here is a link to a page that it works on:
http://plainfoundation.com/hall-of-distinction/

Here is a link to a page that it does not work on:
http://plainfoundation.com/contact/

From my examination using the developer tools provided by Google Chrome and the add-on Firebug for Mozilla Firefox, the code is exactly the same and no issues are appearing in the console. Maybe somebody has an idea and can help with this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you enqueuing the fonts in your functions file?

Comment: The fonts are loaded via the theme through the functions file, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Viewing your source, I see you have @font-face .ttf only, but not any of the other formats required for all browsers. You should make sure you have all these described on this [css-tricks post.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)

Also you seem to be adding this in your header styles. You should make sure this @font-face is declared before other styles load. To ensure that, either place it at the top of your first stylesheet or in a new 'myfonts.css' file and enqueue it in your functions file before other stylesheets:

Here are the formats required:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: But this isn't an issue on any other page, is it?

Comment: Is that page using the same template as any others? Choose another in the dashboard to see if there's a change. Also try commenting out the content in case something there is interfering with that font load.